# All In In Broken Test On Channel 4

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

> When linked with a choice it may well make you whine
>   And when builders have it, oh how they do pine.
>   To some it's an art where deceit may abound
>   Inside a location some suits lead around.
>   It's practically perfect when headed by me
>   It's leading the way for intoxicant free

The answer is a single English word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is:

> Deal.

When linked with a choice it may well make you whine

> Adding OR(choice) to deal, we get ORDEAL which will surely make me whine.

And when builders have it, oh how they do pine

> Builders would love a deal that is fat for their pockets. Also, deal in its noun form means pine or building material.

To some it's an art where deceit may abound

> I feel this is about dishonest deals done by people? Also, As @GarethMcCaughan points out, this may refer to "The Art of the Deal" written by the current President of the United States.

Inside a location some suits lead around.

> I think this is telling about business deals. (Also, lead around could be an anagram indicator. (Lead)*=Deal.)Also, Deal is a part of "insiDE A Location".

It's practically perfect when headed by me

> Adding I to deal, we get IDEAL which means perfect.

It's leading the way for intoxicant free

> This probably means taking measures (meaning of deal) against intoxicants? @Gareth again points out a Dealcoholised which means alcohol-free.(I confess, I had no idea such a word existed).

The title:

> HughMeyers helps here with his original intention: Apparently, in the English channel, in Kent(which lies in broken test) there is a place called "Deal" which is the answer.

Comment: I think the "art where deceit may abound" is a reference to a book written by (or more precisely ghostwritten for) the present President of the United States.

Comment: In your answer for the second line, I believe you mean "noun" instead of "verb". Otherwise correct. :-) There are a few tricks in the fourth line. You've found one.  Any thoughts on the title? (You've earned the tick but I'll let you ponder a moment or two.)

Comment: Oh, the last one is probably about the word "dealcoholized". Not that it's a word I've ever actually seen -- more often it's "alcohol-free" -- but it is in fact a word.

Comment: @Hugh Added my thoughts on the title

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Yes, indeed. It was common in Canada but maybe only there. My apologies if it's a regionalism.

Comment: Congrats! The title was a bit convoluted. In the county of Kent (which is in "Broken Test"), on the English Channel there is a four letter city which is the answer to the puzzle. The 4 was meant to be like  the number of letters you see at the end of a crossword clue. So there you go.